# hex() argument cannot be converted to hex

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to do the following;

```
pin = hex("2FFF6996").replace('L', '').upper()[2:].zfill(8)
```

However I am getting an error - hex() argument cannot be converted to hex.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about `pin = "2FFF6996"`?

Comment: @alko `hex()` can also output an `L`. Try `hex(2**32)` on Python 2.

Comment: Is `"2FFF6996"` a variable in your actual code? What types should you be able to process?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The pin variable is sent to a function, which constructs an AT command; `command = r'AT+SENDMSG=%X,%s,%d,%d' % (pin, message, timeout, print_pending)`. The pin isn't a constant, it is a variable depending on user input. The pin will always be a hex input.

Comment: @TomSothcott Update your question instead of comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pin = hex(int("2FFF6996".replace('L', '').upper()[2:].zfill(8), 16))

>>> pin
'0xff6996'
```

you can remove `upper` and `hex` if you want a number from string to pass it to `print` function like a `%X` parameter:

```
>>> pin = int("2FFF6996".replace('L', '')[2:].zfill(8), 16)
>>> pin
16738710
>>> print "0x%X" % pin
0xFF6996
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However I am passing the pin variable to another function, which takes `%X`. Not sure I am doing it right, as I get a TypeError - `%X format: a number is required, not a str`

Comment: @TomSothcott leave only int: `pin = int("2FFF6996".replace('L', '').upper()[2:].zfill(8), 16)`

Answer (score 2):

Hex expects a number so valid options are:

```
hex(0x2FFF6996) # hex
hex(805267862) # 10 base
hex(05777664626) # 8 base
```

These all generate the following result:
    '0x2fff6996'

Answer (score 0):

`hex` converts an integer into a hex string (See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex)) hence the error.

It seems you already have a hex string, apart from a leading "0x" so this may do what you need:

```
"2FFF6996".replace('L', '').upper()[2:].zfill(8)
```